# Wordpress thinks I am on PHP 5.5 when I'm on 7.3?

Tags: php, wordpress

My website is currently due an update to Wordpress, as well as a number of plugins. I am hosted with Krystal, and I have PHP V7.3 selected, and Wordpress is telling me that I am on PHP 5.5, and as such, will not let me update the website nor it's plugins.

I am definitely running PHP V7.3, could this be because I previously switched host, where I was running PHP 7.1 (highest they allowed)?

I believe the same issue existed with my other host, where I was on PHP 7.1.

Any ideas? I have googled this question a lot but nothing seems to do it?

Thank you!

Comment: If WordPress says you're on PHP 5.5, you probably are. Have your hosting check this for you as this is most likely a server side thing.

Comment: create a php file containing <?php phpinfo(); ?>
post the output here so we could see that exactly the issue is.

Comment: Hi Guys, thank you for your help - it seems the issue was with my .htaccess file? It had some kind of override in it defining the PHP version as "55" (so that's where the 5.5 was from). Thank you for the comments anyway though! Will post the exact problem below for anyone who finds this problem in future.

Answer (score 0):

**"Use PHP55"**

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php55 .php
<IfModule mod_suphp.c>
suPHP_ConfigPath /opt/php55/lib
```

This was the problem code that was causing the issue. It was in the .htaccess file.

Simply remove this code and the problem resolves itself!